# Jsoup fail to get <p> </p>

Tags: jsoup

I try to use Jsoup to get ACM-DL article abstract.
But it is fail to get

It is the website : 
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1999265&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=698338637&CFTOKEN=48876455

It is my code section

```
Elements PapaerElm = PaprtDoc.select("div div div p");
    for(Element tempAbstract :PapaerElm){
            System.out.println(tempAbstract);   
    }
```

How can I correctly get the abstract?

Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved? If yes, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the id of the div is "abstract", you can do this:

```
Element content = document.getElementById("abstract");
```

And then parse the element to get the paragraphs inside the div:

```
Elements paragraphs = content.getElementsByTag("p");
```

And then iterate to find the desired abstract.

Comment: I try this way.
But... still fail...

It cant get the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract is loaded via an AJAX call. I used Chrome network tools to extract this direct URL:

```
http://dl.acm.org/tab_abstract.cfm?id=1999265
```

So it seems that the id comes from your original URL. (I stripped out the other stuff, including the token, since it seems not be needed to just get the abstract)

Comment: Oh! Got it.
Thanks !!

Comment: if this helps, you are free to accept my answer and also up-vote (if you can)